# Java FileChannel.size() vs File.length()

Tags: java, file, io, stream, channel

Are there any circumstances where `FileChannel.size()` and `File.length()` will be different? Please see the code example below:

```
File file = new File(name);
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
FileChannel channel = stream.getChannel();
long channel_size = channel.size();
long file_length = file.length();
```

Comment: Why don't you print out both values and see if they're different?

Comment: @JoshM I think OP is looking for situations where they wouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be different because the `new File(name).length()` always checks the path given.  When you use `FileInputStream`, you attach to that file regardless of what happens to it.

For example, in Linux you can rename, replace or delete a file which is in use.  The `FileInputStream` will continue to give the original file's size whereas the `File` will give you what replaced it, if any.