# Java FileChannel.size() vs File.length() - After FileChannel.truncate()

Tags: java, filesize

I was thinking about changing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293031/java-channel-size-vs-file-length) into my situation.  I then decided that my situation needed its own question and hopefully answers.  After calling `FileChannel.truncate()` to reduce the size of the file, I call `FileChannel.size()`, close the `FileChannel` and then call `File.length()`.  The File exists throughout the entire operation.  `FileChannel.size()` is always accurate.  On a rare occasion, `File.length()` will return the size of the file before `truncate()`.

Here is the code that shows the situation.

```
public static void truncate(File file, long size) throws IOException
{
   FileChannel channel;
   Path path;
   long channelSize, fileLengthOpen, fileLengthClosed;

   path    = file.toPath();
   channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

   try
   {
      channel.truncate(size);

      channelSize    = channel.size();
      fileLengthOpen = file.length();
   }
   finally
   {
      channel.close();
   }

   fileLengthClosed = file.length();

   if ((channelSize != size) || (fileLengthOpen != size) || (fileLengthClosed != size))
      throw new IOException("The channel size or file length does not match the truncate size.  Channel: " + channelSize + " - Open File: " + fileLengthOpen + " - Closed File: " + fileLengthClosed + " - Truncate: " + size);
}
```

On a rare occasion, the code throws the `IOException`.  `channelSize` == `size` and `fileLengthOpen` == `size` but `fileLengthClosed` != `size`.

Why does `fileLengthClosed` != `size`?  How do I ensure `File.length()` matches `FileChannel.size()`?  Flushing the file's metadata would be okay as long as it does not force flushing the file's contents.  Flushing the file's contents would incur unneeded file I/Os.

Answers telling me to use `channelSize` or `fileLengthOpen` or to ignore the problem will not be accepted.  I have another class file that uses `File.length()` to determine the length of the file.  Passing `channelSize` or `fileLengthOpen` to the other class would require passing the value up the stack several frames and then back down several frames.  If you suggest that I use `Files.size()` to fix the problem, please explain why.

I am not sure if this matters.  I am running Java 10 on Linux.  (Yeah, I know Java 10 is old, but I am stuck with it until I can implement the necessary features to upgrade to Java 11.)

Edit: In the past, multi-threaded updates on files has caused problems.  For this reason, I created a file locking mechanism so that only 1 thread in the entire process can exclusively operate on a file (or multiple threads can read the file).  Furthermore, the `File` object passed to my `truncate()` was created by the calling thread and is only used by that thread. I can guarantee that no other thread in the process can operate on the file on disk or the `File` object.

Edit: I changed the code to call `Files.size()` before and after `channel.close()`.  `channel.size()`, `File.length()` and `Files.size()` report the correct size while `channel` is open.  Right after `channel.close()`, `File.length()` and `Files.size()` are on the rare occasion the original longer file length and not the truncated shorter length.

Comment: Why *aren't* you using `Files.size()` anyway? The `File` class should be allowed to die in peace already. Have you tried to see if you have that problem with `Files.size()`?

Comment: Windows is known to not update file metadata while the file is open.

Comment: I have about 90 places in my code base where `File.length()` is used.  I will make the code change to `Files.size()` if I can prove it fixes the problem.  I changed `truncate()` to check `Files.size()` before and after closing the `FileChannel` and I will see what happens... it may take a few days to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem does not reproduce on Windows.  But, that does not say much since the problem does not reproduce very often on Linux.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I updated the question after using `Files.size()`.  `Files.size()` has the same problem as `File.length()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spin wait for `fileLengthClosed` to be correct. Here is the code.

```
while (true)
{
   fileLengthClosed = file.length();

   if (fileLengthClosed == size)
      break;

   Thread.sleep(1);
}
```

I have run this code for 3 weeks and there have been no issues.  One concern is that there is no timeout code in case the file length is modified or the `file.length()` never updates.

This solution does not answer why `File.length()` is incorrect in the first place. Also, calling `Thread.sleep()` suggests that I am really waiting for some other operation to complete and I really should force that operation to complete or block on that operation. I am not sure how to force or block on that operation.